# Building a dictionary in a form of a linked-list and getting a Segmentation fault (core dumped) error

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I understand that a Segmentation fault (core dump) error is because I am trying to access memory that I don't have access to, but I don't understand why it does it to my program.

I'm sure that the problem comes from the `printList(node *head)` function, but I don't understand why.

In this code, I have to take a user input and create a dictionary in a form of a linked list. Here is the full code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<string.h>

//To count the number of times an element was added to the dictionary
static int countWords=0;

typedef struct node{

    char string[255]; //store the data
    struct node *next; //pointer to the next structure -> this is a pointer

}node;

//Prints the list
void printList(node *head){

    node *p = head;

    do{
        for(int i=0; i<255; i++)
            printf("%c", p->string[i]);
        p = p -> next;
    }
    while(p->next != NULL);

}

//Inserts the word in alphabetical order in the list
node *insert_dictionary_order(char *pWord, node *dictionary){

    node *head = dictionary; //head of the first node
    node *temp = NULL; //Node that will be placed in the linked list
    node *p = NULL; //iterator 

    //creating individual isolated nodes -> not attached to a list
    temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));

    //This stores the values that pointer gives us in an array
    char word[255];
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
        word[i] = *(pWord + i);

    //instantiating the node member
    temp->next = NULL;
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
        temp -> string[i] = word[i];

    //LinkedList is still empty
    if(head == NULL){
        printf("\nWe get here4!!\n");
        head = temp;
        printList(head); //THIS DOESNT WORK
        printf("\nWe get here5!!\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("\nWe get here6!!\n");
        p = head;
        //Comparing temp to words in the dictionary
        //To know if we are at the first iteration (changing the head)
        do{

            printf("New word: %s\nDictionary Word: %s\n", temp -> string, p->string);

            if(strcmp(temp->string, p->string) < 0 && countWords ==0){ //Special case for the head
                temp -> next = p;
                head = temp;
                countWords++;           
            }
            //Checking if we are at inserting position
            else if(strcmp(temp->string, p->string) > 0 && strcmp(temp->string, (p->next)->string) < 0){
                temp->next = p->next;
                p->next = temp;
                countWords++;
            }

            p = p->next;                
        }
        while(p->next != NULL);
    }
    printList(head);
    return head;
}

//To check if a certain character is a letter
int isALetter(char c){

    if((c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || 
    c == '\0')
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

int main(){

    node *dictionary = NULL;

    //Prompting the user to enter strings
    printf("Please enter some strings.\n");

    //To store the strings that the user enters 
    char string[10000];
    fgets(string, 10000, stdin);

    //Putting the string to lower case for easy manipulations
    for(int i=0; i<10000; i++)
        string[i] = tolower(string[i]);

    //To put the word in an array
    char word[255];
    //looping through the strings
    int i=0;
    //looping through the word
    int j = 0;

    //Checking the strings to put the words in the dictionary
    do{
        //Checking if we need to escape the loop
        if(i>0 && ((string[i] == '.' && string[i-1]== ' ' )|| string[i] == 0))
            break;

        //Checking if a letter
        if(isALetter(string[i]) == 0){
            i++;
            continue;
        }   

        //Checking if end of the word
        if(isALetter(string[i+1]) == 0)
        {       
            word[j] = string[i];

            printf("\n");
            char *pWord;
            pWord = word;

            printf("\nWe get here1!!\n");
            //Adding word to the dictionary
            dictionary = insert_dictionary_order(pWord, dictionary);

            //***trying stuff
            printf("\nWe get here2!!\n");

            //***Printing the updated linked list
            //printList(dictionary);    

            //***trying stuff
            printf("\nWe get here3!!\n");

            //reseting the word array
            memset(word, 0, 255);   

            j = 0;
            i++;
            continue;
        }
        word[j] = string[i];
        j++;
        i++;
    }
    while(i != 10000);

    //Printing the list
    printf("\n\nPrinting the list..\n\n");

    printList(dictionary);


    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
Please enter some strings.
zz aa


We get here1!!

We get here4!!
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

We can clearly see that the problem comes from the `printList(node *head)` method with this output, since the "We get here!!" number 2, 3, 5 and 6 dont appear (they are all after a call to this method).

Comment: The best advice is to use a debugger. Even if someone finds the problem for you here (which I'm sure they will) it will be better in the long run for you to learn effective debugging for yourself. At a minimum, the debugger will tell you immediately and exactly which line of code is causing the seg fault and will allow you to examine all the variables.

Comment: @kaylum thanks for the advice!

Comment: Why do you copy the string to an intermediate array just to copy it onwards from there to final target? Copy it from source to target directly, skipping that intermediate entirely.

Comment: `isALetter` – have you heard of standard library functions like isdigit, isalpha, isalnum, isspace, etc?

Comment: `for(int i=0; i<5; i++) temp -> string[i] = word[i];` – why only 5 characters? Apart from, you get that much simpler by `memcpy(temp->string, word, 5);`...

Comment: `for(int i=0; i<255; i++) printf("%c", p->string[i]);` – you really want to print all the null characters at the end? If you guarantee that the string will be null-terminated, you can print much simpler by `printf("%s", p->string);`.

Comment: `do{ p = p -> next;} while(p->next != NULL);`. That's probably the source of your problem. By the time the `while` condition is checked the `p` value will be NULL on the last iteration. You have other problems in the code too.

Comment: Off-topic: please don't write code like `if(condition) return 1; else return 0;`, just write `return condition;` standard already guarantees that the result of comparisons and logical operations (&&, ||) result in either 1 or 0...

Comment: `'a <= letter <= 'z'` is not fully portable, by the way. There are character sets like the (in-?)famous EBCDIC where letters are not grouped subsequently. You wouldn't have this problem with `isalpha` (as hinted to already).

Comment: `strcmp > 0 && strcmp < 0`: You do not handle duplicates that way. To catch these, you should include equality in one of the comparisons.

Comment: `*(pWord + i);` can be written much simpler: `pword[i]`. Actually, the latter is just syntactic sugar for the former. You'll notice if you try `i[pword]`: You'll discover that it is totally valid and will produce the same result...

Answer (score 0):

As kaylum commented, use a debugger. If you did, you'd see this:

```
Please enter some strings.
aa zz


We get here1!!

We get here4!!

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000555555555334 in printList (head=0x612000000040) at t.c:26
26          while(p->next != NULL);
(gdb) p p
$1 = (node *) 0x0
```

Which is the source of your bug (as kaylum also already commented).